# Creating a local database for Visual Studio & SVN

Tags: c#, visual-studio, connection

at the moment I am experimenting with the new Visual Studio 2012 and MVC4. I would like to create a .mdf database and use migrations for it. The migrations part is no problem here but when sharing the project on subversion it says invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename' when someone else (on another pc) opens it.

I think something is wrong with the connection string but I don't know what. By running the project it automatically creates a database named "CarDealer.DAL.CarDealerContext.mdf". I manually edited the default connection string to the following:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|CarDealer.DAL.CarDealerContext.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
```

I would be happy if someone could change this connection string so I and colleagues can work on the project on different pc's :) thanks in advance.

Just so you know. The other person is using VS 2010, could it have to do something with localDb v11?

--UPDATE--

Well another colleague tested it and I also did it on another system. We're also getting an error but it's not the same one. It's the following [d.pr/i/g6NM](http://d.pr/i/g6NM) . Using the following connection string:

```
< add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CarDealer.DAL.CarDealerCont‌​ext.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a backslash:

```
|DataDirectory|CarDealer.DAL.CarDealerContext.mdf
```

should be

```
|DataDirectory|\CarDealer.DAL.CarDealerContext.mdf
```

EDIT:

If he's using VS2010, it's possible that doesn't like localdb.  Try using an SQL express connection instead, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem. He still receives the same error.

Comment: Does the `App_Data` folder exist on his machine?

Comment: Yes, and the db is in there (just a checkout from SVN). Btw I edited my post mentioning he is using VS 2010

Comment: You should try SQL Express and see if the problem disappears - if the problem remains then you've ruled out localdb being the problem.

Comment: So I changed the data source to .\SQLExpress now and he's still getting the error :/

Comment: That's just odd, and perhaps suggests that something else on your colleague's machine isn't upto date.

Comment: Well another colleague tested it and I also did it on another system. We're also getting an error but it's not the same one. It's the following http://d.pr/i/g6NM . 

Using the following connection string
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CarDealer.DAL.CarDealerContext.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />

Answer (score 0):

I could not find out what the problem is. Probably it's a bit too early to work with Visual Studio 2012. I think the problems are, as said before, caused by elements that aren't up to date. I just rebuild the project in VS 2010 and will go on with this one..